# FileLoadException when using Microsoft Unity configuration

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-container, fileloadexception

A FileLoadException when using Unity generally means that a type has been configured for that cannot be loaded because the assembly has not been reference by the project.

How can I find out what type is trying to be resolved so that a reference can be added to the project (or remove an unused type that is configured in the app.config).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn on the debug exceptions (Debug>Exceptions ... Ctrl+D, E) and turn on the `System.IO.FileLoadException`

When I did this I was able to hover over the type that was being resolved which pointed at an extra type that was specified in the app.config file.

It failed in `TypeResolverImpl.SearchAssemblies(string typeNameOrAlias)`

If you hover over the `typeNameOrAlias` variable you'll see the type it is resolving.